# Replace substring with wildcard in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write an SQL update to replace a specific CSS property with a blank so I can remove it.

Let's see:

```
UPDATE table
SET css_string = REPLACE(css_string, "top:calc(50%%ANY_VALUE%%) !important;", " ");
```

So that I can remove the `top:calc(50% - 20px) !important;` property from the CSS string.

Comment: What difficult are you experiencing? what does and doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it, been a while since I have worked with SQL:

```
UPDATE table
SET css_string = REPLACE(css_string,"top:calc(50%) !important;"," ");
```

Before you go updating you can run some queries like:

```
Select css_string, REPLACE(css_string,"top:calc(50%) !important;"," ") as "change to" from table
```